# Jacobi/Heliocentric coordinates conversion

Tags: astrophysics, coordinate-systems, computational-physics

I am using a program that is an N-Body integrator.

The program allows me to input the initial conditions of my system (position and velocity or the initial orbital elements of each particle in the system), and does so in the heliocentric frame.

However, to know how the system evolved in time, there is a function that outputs the orbital elements of each particle, but the elements are calculated using the Jacobi coordinates.

Is there a way to reconcile the input with the output? i.e at $t = 0$ I want to input the initial conditions and I want the output function to output the same numbers I provide. Is there a conversion technique?

Comment: Presumably one was constructed from the other.  In what basis are the Jacobi coordinates (these are not a basis, they are just using barycenters instead of individual planet locations)?